# Set default value of one column to another column in INSERT Statement

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table, call it t1, with three integer columns c1, c2, c3. c1 has a default value of:

```
not null default nextval
```

For the INSERT statements I am currently doing, I want c2 to have the same value as will be assigned to c1. This is not the case for most of my inserts so it does not make sense to define c2 to have a default value or to have a trigger on update. Currently I am doing two statements:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c3) VALUES (val3);
UPDATE t1 SET c2 = c1 WHERE //Get correct row
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is *no guarantee* in which order elements of a set will be processed. There is also *no need* to make two function calls. Use a sub-select or a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
INSERT INTO t (c1, c2, c3)
SELECT x.s, x.s, val3
FROM  (SELECT nextval('c1_seq') AS s) x;
```

Or with a CTE:

```
WITH   x(s) AS (SELECT nextval('c1_seq'))
INSERT INTO t (c1, c2, c3)
SELECT x.s, x.s, val3
FROM   x;
```

Comment: This type of CTE is new in version 9.1, it won't work in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for `c1` will only be used if you don't supply an explicit value for it or, of course, if you explicitly ask for the default value with `default` in your VALUES. You are also free to access the sequence yourself using [`nextval` and `currval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) inside your VALUES; the `nextval` function does this:

> Advance sequence and return new value.

and `currval`:

> Return value most recently obtained with nextval for specified sequence

So you could do this to get the next sequence value for `c1` and get the same value for `c2`:

```
insert into t1 (c1, c2, c3) values (nextval('c1_seq'), currval('c1_seq'), val3)
```

where `c1_seq` is the name of the sequence that you're using to supply default values for `c1`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you need to set the default value for *c2* to the current value of the sequence, associated with *c1*, i.e.:

```
ALTER TABLE
  t1
ALTER COLUMN
  c2
SET DEFAULT
  CURRVAL(PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('t1', 'c1'));
```

Of course, that won't work in case you specify some explicit value for *c1*. If there are such cases, then you should make a BEFORE trigger, in order to be sure that *c2* will **always** be the same as *c1* on insert.

```
CREATE FUNCTION sync_c2() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.c2 IS NULL THEN
    NEW.c2 := NEW.c1;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER
  sync_c2
BEFORE INSERT ON
  t1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  sync_c2();
```

Comment: The IF check in the trigger gives you the freedom to explicitly specify values for c2 different from c1, if you wish to.